# Как изменить title в html документе

Tags: javascript, html

В чатах, когда приходит сообщение, с помощью очевидно JS меняют title - так мы видим, что пришло сообщение. Подскажите, как это сделать?

Comment: Можно менять favicon: http://lab.ejci.net/favico.js/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для этого достаточно просто менять `document.title`, к примеру:

```
document.title = 'Новое сообщение';
```

Но учтите что в плане SEO это не одобряют.